# Ordernar tabela por valor contido

Tags: lua, lua-table

Quero ordenar tal tabela por um valor contido nela. Ex:

```
tabela = {
{pessoa="Joao", idade=20},
{pessoa="Pedro", idade=22},
{pessoa="Lucas", idade=19},
{pessoa="Derp", idade=25}
}
```

Quero ordenar a tabela pela idade.
Algo como:

```
table.sort(tabela, function(table, value1, value2) return table.value1 < table.value2 end)
for x=1, table.maxn(tabela) do
print(tabela[x].idade)
end
```

Retornaria:

```
25
22
20
19
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você chegou perto. Mas tem três erros.

- Você está recebendo os parâmetros de forma indevida. Esta *lambda* que o `table.sort` espera recebe apenas dois parâmetros que representam os dois items a serem comparados. Estes itens são valores independentes, você não precisa e nem pode receber a tabela. Da maneira como fez você está recebendo a tabela e pegando os itens dela. Desta forma, em tese, você nem precisaria dos parâmetros subsequentes. Mas é justamente o contrário do que você precisa. Esta *lambda* não pode ter a assinatura que você quiser porque ela será chamada pelo `table.sort`. Ela precisa estar de acordo com a especificação estabelecida.
- Você está pegando o item todo para comparar ao invés do item específico, ou seja, você precisa pegar a idade da tabela e não a tabela que a função recebe. Não sei se você percebeu você tem uma tabela aninhada. Então sua função anônima passada para o `table.sort` está recebendo uma tabela com os itens `pessoa` e `idade`. Até aí tudo certo. Mas você está tentando comparar **a tabela** e não dá (não confundir com a tabela principal, é a tabela interior, ex.: `{pessoa="Joao", idade=20}`). Você precisa comparar um item da tabela. Este item é a `idade`.
- E você mostrou que quer a ordenação decrescente o que obrigaria a comparação ser com sinal de "maior que". Você provavelmente iria perceber isto quando resolvesse o problema anterior.

Então ficaria algo assim:

```
tabela = {
    {pessoa = "Joao", idade = 20},
    {pessoa = "Pedro", idade = 22},
    {pessoa = "Lucas", idade = 19},
    {pessoa = "Derp", idade = 25}
}
table.sort(tabela, function(value1, value2) return value1.idade > value2.idade end)
for x = 1, table.maxn(tabela) do
    print(tabela[x].idade)
end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/EHOpqN). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/eoeowzozbo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/TableSort.lua).

Comment: Perfeito, melhor explicação, impossível. Funcionou aqui.

Comment: +1 Isso é uma bíblia pra quem está aprendendo